# How to close the drive

Tags: c++

I have a code which will un-hide all files present in the removable drive

```
//buffer is the removable drive letter
PWSTR show = L"/k attrib -s -r -h *.* /s /d /l ";
ShellExecute(NULL,L"open",L"cmd.exe",show,buffer,SW_HIDE);
```

This code works successfully but after performing this operation I cannot eject my removable drive.
It shows the following message
[image]

Even when I close my program it shows this message. When seeing the task manager I found that my drive I:\ is running in the background what should I do now to solve this

Comment: your executed program is still running, try changing SW_HIDE to SW_NORMAL and see.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The switch `/k` makes `cmd.exe` run a command then sit there waiting for further instructions.
Your shell window is still there, in the background, hidden, sitting on `I:`.

Replace `/k` with `/c`.

---

> ```
> /C     Run Command and then terminate
>
> /K     Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.
>        This is useful for testing, to examine variables
> ```

<sup>(http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html)</sup>